# How can I use python to get rendered ASP pages?

Tags: python, asp-classic

I'm trying to use python to navigate through a website that have auth forms on its landing page, rendered by ASP scripts.

But when I use python (with mechanize, requests, or urlibs) to get the HTML of that site, I always end up with  a semi-blank HTML file, due to such ASP scripts.

Would anyone know any method that I can use to get the final (as displayed on a browser) version of an ASP site?

Comment: Is the content being modified/loaded using JavaScript?

Comment: Have you tried a higher level browser emulator like Selenium?

Comment: If it really is the ASP scripts refusing to serve you content because you're coming from Python instead of a browser, it's just a matter of changing your HTTP headers (most likely the User-Agent header), because there is literally no other way they can possibly distinguish between your script and, say, Firefox. However, it's very likely that you're wrong about the problem, and the ASP is serving the exact same combination of HTML and JS, and the problem (as @Blender says) is that the additional HTML is generated by the JS.

Comment: @Blender No, in this case, it's just ASP.

Comment: @sr2222 Just tried Selenium, but got the same results. It didn't rendered the fields i'm looking for.

Comment: @abarnert I tried it, as you've said, but I still got the same results.

Comment: BTW, the webpage I'm talking about is [this](http://www010.dataprev.gov.br/cws/contexto/aguia02/aguia02.html)

Comment: When you say "I tried it", what exactly did you try?

Comment: Looking at that page, and throwing everything I can think of at it, there is nothing ASP-relevant going on at all. The ASP pages are serving the exact same content to my `requests`-based code as they are to Google Chrome. There is no AJAX code on the pages to make further requests of the ASP scripts, or anything like that. A simple `wget`-based mirror of the site works exactly the same as the original site. So, ASP is not the issue here.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by "it's just ASP", because there very definitely is JS here, both in the `frameset` and in the embedded `frame`. The JS doesn't seem to be the cause of your problems either, but if you're sure there's no JS when there obviously is, that's not a good sign that you've understood the basics of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Your target page](http://www010.dataprev.gov.br/cws/contexto/aguia02/aguia02.html) is a `frameset`. There is nothing fancy going on from the server side that I can tell. When I use `requests` or `urllib` to download it, even sending no headers at all, I get exactly the same HTML that I see in Chrome or Firefox. There is some embedded JS, but it doesn't do anything. Basically, all there is here is a `frameset` with a single `frame` in it.

The [`frame`](http://www010.dataprev.gov.br/cws/contexto/aguia02/aguia02inicio.HTML) target is also a perfectly normal page with nothing fancy going on from the server side that I can tell. Again, if I fetch it with no headers, I get the exact same contents as in Chrome or Firefox. There is plenty of embedded JS here, but it's not building the DOM from scratch or anything; the static contents that I get from the server have the whole page contents in them. I can strip out all the JS and render it, and it looks exactly the same.

There is a minor problem that neither the server nor the HTML specifies a charset anywhere, and yet the contents aren't ASCII, which means you need to guess what charset to decode if you want to process it as Unicode. But if you're in Python 2.x, and just planning to grab things out of the DOM by ID or something, that won't matter.

I suspect your real problem is just that you don't know how HTML `frameset`s work. You're downloading the `frameset`, not downloading the referenced `frame`, and wondering why the resulting page looks like an empty `frameset`.

Frames are an obsolete feature that nobody uses anymore for anything but a common trick for letting the user pop up a new window even in ancient browsers, and some obscure tricks for fooling popup blockers. In HTML 5 they're finally gone. But as long as ancient websites are out there and need to be scraped, you need to know how they work.

This isn't a substitute for the full documentation, but here's the short version of what a web browser does with a `frameset`: For each `frame` tag, it follows the `src` attribute, then it replaces the contents of the `frame` tag with a `#document` tag with no attributes, with the results of reading the `src` URL as its contents. Beyond that, of course, frames affect layout, but that probably doesn't affect you.

Meanwhile, if you're trying to learn web scraping, you really want to install your browser's "Web Developer Tools" (different browsers have different names), or a full-on debugger like Firebug. That way, you can inspect the live tree that your browser is rendering, and compare it to what you get from your script (or, more simply, from `wget`). So, next time you can say "In Chrome's Inspect Page, I see a `#document` under the `frame`, with a whole bunch of stuff underneath that, but when I try to read the same page myself, the `frame` has no children".

Comment: Thanks, I really did not know of the existence of framesets. I will study them and see if I can help myself.

Comment: @tilacog: Edited the answer with a bit of information to get you started.

Comment: After reading your new answer I managed to access my target page with Python. Thank you very much for your magnificent explanation of framesets!